# Structure a string like a JSON file c++

Tags: c++, json, string, dictionary

I have a string `std::string sub("{\"color\": \"green\",\"type\": \"primary\"}");`.
I parse it and the result is:

```
color:green
type:primary
```

I want to reorganize the structure to be a valid JSON expression, something like this:

```
{
"color": "yellow",
"type": "primary"
}
```

I know that i have to use something like `to string method` but i don't know how to do this. After this i want to could acces the elemets of the strings, like `get(color)`.
NOTE: my `color:green, type:primary` are `std::map<std::string,string> keyVal` type.

Comment: Their are plenty of json libraries to do this for you, it's not a trivial task.

Comment: "I parse it and the result is" show us how you do that, we can't guess your implementation

Comment: Note you can use RAW strings so you don't need to escape the `"` character. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: A list of C++ json parser can be found here: https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boost json parser

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree.html

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
    try{
        ptree pt;
        json_parser::read_json("file.json", pt); // <- invalid will be caught
        std::string color = pt.get<std::string>("color");
        std::string something = pt.get<std::string>("root.path.to.key");
    }catch(...)
    {
        std::cout<<"invalid!"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For config style data go for [write_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681439/boostproperty-treeinfo-parser-breaks-on-spaces-in-value) and [read_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681439/boostproperty-treeinfo-parser-breaks-on-spaces-in-value).

If you prefer to work with strings than files, for string to json properties, follow

```
const std::string json="{\"color\": \"green\",\"type\": \"primary\"}";
ptree pt;
std::istringstream i_str(json);
read_json(i_str, pt);
```

and for json properties to a string:

```
const ptree pt=...;
std::ostringstream buf; 
write_json(buf, pt, false);
std::string json = buf.str(); // {"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: you need to elaborate on that. "boost::write_info" via "std::wostringstream", etc.

Comment: it is on hold(why?).but: wostringstream str;  write_json(str,pt);      cout<<str.str();                               OP needs string IMO.

Comment: @Red.Wave, the question is a bit vague to me. But thank you very much for mentioning this.

Comment: y r welcome. that could be my answer in your absence. I guess the OP needs the output in a string, rather than a file. Therefore the more generic answer would be the one involving iostreams instead of filenames.